# How can I collect all implementations of one interface using Play Framwork

Tags: playframework

I have several implementations of `Converter` to build **Strategy Mode**. Now I need to collect all implementations of `Converter` in order to choose different convert strategy in runtime.

Like `Spring boot`, I can use

```java
applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Converter.class)
```

to achieve that.

I wonder how I can do the similar things in Play Framework!

Comment: Are you using Java or Scala?

Comment: I use Java in Play Framework